# Google App Script - Ignore Case When Removing Duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found a Google App Script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125877/845709) by Cooper, user:7215091, from this thread

And it works perfectly for my needs where I too was removing duplicates from a Google Sheet looking at values in column B in a sheet that is constantly being updated by outside users.

The only thing I want it to do is ignore case. What needs to be edited so that it will remove duplicates, ignoring the case? For example it finds "Bob", "bob", and "boB" and it removes two, doesn't matter which.

```
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var nA=[];
  var duplicate=true;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    duplicate=false;
    for(var j=0;j<nA.length;j++)
    {
      if(vA[i][1]==nA[j][1])
      {
        duplicate=true;
        nA[j]=vA[i];
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate)
    {
      nA.push(vA[i]);
    }
  }
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(row, col, nA.length, nA[0].length).setValues(nA);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **toLowerCase()** to convert each of the strings to lowercase letters and compare them.

```
  if(vA[i][1].toLowerCase() === nA[j][1].toLowerCase())
  {
    duplicate=true;
    nA[j]=vA[i];
  }
```